# Making A Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary with Bob's sayings, but I keep being told that I'm using "invalid syntax." What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to pull random keys from the dictionary and display quotes...

```
bob_sayings = { 1: "I wish I was where I was when I wished I was here", 
   2:"There's a fine line between fishing and standing on the shore like an idiot.", 
   3: "After accomplishing a goal just look around to see whether you lost something or someone"}

bob_sayings

bob_sayings[randint(1, 3)
```

Comment: No need for a dictionnary if your keys are integers

Comment: No need for a dictionary if your keys are *sequential* integers

Comment: What should I use instead? I want to have a number be chosen at random and then display it's respective quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, you're getting syntax errors because you're missing a right square bracket a the end of your code.

As others have mentioned you don't need to use a dictionary when the keys are sequential integers. Instead you might try using a list or a tuple. Then you can use `random.choice` instead so you won't have to mess around with indexes. The major benefit of doing it this way is you can add items to the sequence and you won't have to change your code elsewhere. Here is an example.

```
import random

bob_sayings = ( 
    "I wish I was where I was when I wished I was here", 
    "There's a fine line between fishing and standing on the shore like an idiot.", 
    "After accomplishing a goal just look around to see whether you lost something or someone"
)

bob_says = random.choice(bob_sayings)
print(bob_says)
```

Answer (score 2):

You invalid syntax comes from the last line, where you don't close the bracket. Also, in the second line, you have a variable that does nothing.

Anyway, the important thing: Dictionaries are supposed to have keys that *mean something*. In your case, this looks more like a list disguised as a dictionary. A better way would be to write something like

```
from random import choice
sayings = ['something', 'something else', 'another thing']
print(choice(sayings))
```

Comment: In Spyder, I'm being told that the invalid syntax is on the first line...

Comment: @JoeyJayman: maybe spyder doesn't recognise it because it continues in another line. It is correct though, the only real judge is the python interpreter. IDEs suggestions are usually helpful, but *can* go wrong in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
bob_sayings = { 1: "I wish I was where I was when I wished I was here", 2:"There's a fine line between fishing and standing on the shore like an idiot.", 3: "After accomplishing a goal just look around to see whether you lost something or someone"}
bob_sayings[randint(1, 3)]
```

you were missing a `]` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include

`from random import randint`

on the first line. Also you need to add the `]` to the end of your last line.

```
from random import randint

bob_sayings = { 1: "I wish I was where I was when I wished I was here",
   2:"There's a fine line between fishing and standing on the shore like an idiot.",
   3: "After accomplishing a goal just look around to see whether you lost something 
   or someone"}

bob_sayings

bob_sayings[randint(1, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot bracket at the end of bob_sayings[random.randint(1, 3)]

```
import random
bob_sayings = { 1: "I wish I was where I was when I wished I was here", 2:"There's a fine line between fishing and standing on the shore like an idiot.", 3: "After accomplishing a goal just look around to see whether you lost something or someone"}

bob_sayings

bob_sayings[random.randint(1, 3)]
```

Comment: In Spyder, I'm being told that the invalid syntax is on the first line...